# Secure reverse routing

Tags: playframework-2.0

What's the equivalent of `@{Admin.login().secure()}` in Play 2.0 ?

For reference, if the route file was

```
GET /login  Admin.login
```

Admin.login().secure() would return `https://myserver/login`

Note the **https**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```scala
routes.Admin.login().absoluteURL(secure = true)
```